# Is this the right way to prove basic limit identities?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

For example let's say I wanted to prove that:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0$$

Normally I would use epsilon-delta for such proofs but then I start out with conditions like:

$|\frac{1}{x} - 0| < \epsilon$

$0 < |x - \infty| < \delta$

And I don't know how we're supposed to do epsilon-delta proofs for things approaching infinity, if it even makes sense to do this.

Comment: The way to say that $x$ is close to infinity is $\delta <x$, where $\delta$ quantifies the magnitude of how close it is. So, the definition becomes $\forall \epsilon>0,\ \exists \delta:\ \delta<x\implies |1/x|<\epsilon$. You can just take $\delta(\epsilon)=1/\epsilon$ or anything larger.

Comment: Do you actually know the definition of $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$? Because at no point in the definition is there an inequality that looks like $0 < |x - \infty| < \delta$.

Comment: Note: $\delta <x$ actually expresses that $x$ is $\delta$-close to $+\infty$. If one means $\infty$ as both directions $\pm\infty$, then the way of expressing it is $\delta<|x|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infinty creates a mess of things...

What is infinity?  Loosely, it is something bigger than any natural number $N$

When you have a limit $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} f(x) = L$

You get rid of the $\delta$ in your definition and you replace it with something based on $N$

$\forall \epsilon>0\exists N>0: x>N \implies |f(x) - L| <\epsilon$

If you want to prove

$\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x) = \infty$

You replace $\epsilon$ with $M$

$\forall M>0\exists \delta>0: |x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)| >M$

Nothing has fundmentally changed from the definitions, it is just that we expect $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ to be small things and $M, N$ to be big things.

As far as a picture, How about this?

[image]

Comment: Is there a graphical representation of these ideas sort of like https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/L%C3%ADmite_01.svg/1200px-L%C3%ADmite_01.svg.png for regular epsilon-delta? I can't seem to find one on Google

Comment: Also what does $\forall \epsilon>0\exists N>0: x>N \implies |f(x) - L| <\epsilon$ mean in words? For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $N > 0$ ... something where $x > N$ implying $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$

Comment: For any arbitrarily small $\epsilon$, there is some (large) $N$ such that when $x$ is greater than $N, f(x)$ will be within distance $\epsilon$ of $L$

Comment: The colon is used to represent "such that"? I also see $\ni$ on Google? Is there a difference?

Comment: I don't think that one gets much use.  I have also seen (and used) the pipe "|" to mean such that.

Comment: Your equation for infinity using $M$, did you mean to say $|f(x)| > M$ ?

Comment: @user525966 Yes, I did.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in this case the definition of limit requires to find an $\bar x$ such that $$\forall x > \bar x \implies|\frac{1}{x} - 0| < \epsilon$$

Thus in this case, as for the sequences, you don't have a "small" $\delta$ but a "big" $\bar x$ for which the condition holds.